# Can we set an order for class properties before binding the data to an excel?

Tags: c#, oop, properties

In c# using reflection i am getting the property names of a class and then getting the value of those properties and biding the values to an excel.

```
var userData = BAL.GetUserData();
foreach(var result in userData)
{
row.cells[0].value = result.UserId;
int index = 1;
foreach(var item in result.userOptions)
{
 Option op = new Option;
 PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Option).GetProperties();
 foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
 {
   row.Cells[index].value = porperty.GetValue(item);
   index++;
 }
}
}
```

The issue is that the column names is my excel are already defined in an order and i need to bind values to the columns, using the above lines of code i am able achieve what is required as i  defined the property names of my Option class in the same order which is defined in the excel.

```
 Public class Option
   {
     Public string OptionText {get;set;}
     public string OptionValue {get;set;}
     public string OptionRange {get;set;}
     public string OptionStep {get;set;}
   }
```

In future if some other developer tries to change the properties of the Option class in some other order it will mess up my excel data, so i am looking if there is someway i can set an order for the class properties.

Comment: You could add an attribute with an integer as a parameter and sort your `PropertyInfo`s by that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

[`Type.GetProperties()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=net-5.0):

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies.

They happen to be returned in order as defined in code since the beginning of .NET, but the documentation always made clear that this was not guaranteed. So you need to sort the obtained `PropertyInfo` instances in your code anyway.

Sort them either by:

- Determining the order using attributes, for example using [`[Display(Order = n)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.order?view=net-5.0)
- Hardcoding the order in your `Option` class using a string array
- Reading the Excel headers first